# Bootstrap adding extra field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get an extra 'Message' field when clicking on the 'Add' button but for some reason it doesn't work. I want a new 'message' box appearing under the current message box. Including the add en remove button.

I've already read through all the related topics on this site but still can't figure it out.

Do I need to put the 'message' field in an extra form? Or am I taking the wrong 'class' in the js script?

**Index.php**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group2">
             <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
             <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
         <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
         <div class="action">
            <input type="button" name="clone" class="btn btn-success btn-file" value="Add">
            <input type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-file" value="Remove">
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
      <div class="input-group">
             <label class="input-group-btn">
              <span class="btn btn-default btn-send">
                 Browse&hellip; 
                 <input type="file" name="file" style="display: none;">
               </span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</form>

</div><!-- /.8 -->

</div> <!-- /.row-->

</div> <!-- /.container-->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="validator.js"></script>
<script src="document.js"></script>
<script src="extra.js"></script>
```

**extra.js**

```
var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".form-group2").length;

function clone(){
    $(this).parents(".form-group2").clone()
        .appendTo("body")
        .attr("id", "form-group2" +  cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
            }
        })
        .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
        .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
    cloneIndex++;
}
function remove(){
    $(this).parents(".form-group2").remove();
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);
```

[image]

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry, slipped in by mistake. I've removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not `button` (they're `input`) and they don't have the classes `clone` and `remove` attached to them. So add the classes to the HTML and select them by using `input` instead of `button`.

**HTML:** (notice `class="... clone"` and `class="... remove"`)

```
<input type="button" name="clone" class="btn btn-success btn-file clone" value="Add">
<input type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-file remove" value="Remove">
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$("input.clone").on("click", clone);
$("input.remove").on("click", remove);
```

Or you can use IDs which is better (`#clone` and `#remove`).

---

**EDIT:**

you use `apendTo('body')` which will add it to the end of the body. Instead use `insertAfter` which will add it just after an element. This code will add the clone element just after the original element:

```
function clone(){
    var elem = $(this).parents(".form-group2");
    elem.clone()
        .insertAfter(elem)
        .attr("id", "form-group2" +  cloneIndex)
    //...
```

**EDIT 2:**

The newly added elements won't have the event listener atached (or they won't have them attached properly). So instead of attaching the events directly to the buttons use event delegation like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "input.clone", clone);
$(document).on("click", "input.remove", remove);
```

this two line should replace the previous two lines (in the **JAVASCRIPT:** section above). Event delegation won't attach the event listeners directly to an element, but instead it will attach them to another element (the first parameter: `document`) so whenever that element is clicked, it will look if the target element match a selector (the second parameter), if match then executes the function (the third parameter). Before, the event listeners were directly attached to the already existing buttons so the new ones have to reattach them every time they're created but this is not convenient, so we use delegation to delegate that event listener to a known element which will listen to the event and then check if the target element match a specified selector no matter wether that element is just been added (a clone) or not (the original).

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I have a new issue now. The new field doesn't come under the current box, but at the end of the page. See picture in my original question

Comment: where do you want it to be?

Comment: @WouterS if you want to add the new element just after its original element see the **EDIT** section in the answer above.

Comment: thank you for your help, it works. But now I have an other issue.When I click "add" than a new field comes up but the buttons in the new field don't work. Why is that?

Comment: @WouterS see **EDIT 2:**.